# Proof comparing $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ as $n\to\infty$ of $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{c_{n+1}-c_n}$and $\frac{a_n}{c_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

If {${c_n}$}$_{0}^{\infty}$is a sequence of positive numbers increasing to $+\infty$ and if {${a_n}$}$_{0}^{\infty}$ is any sequence of real numbers then

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{c_{n+1}-c_n}\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{c_n}\le \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{c_n}\le \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{c_{n+1}-c_n}.$$

I am trying to prove this theorem but I am struggling with how to go about doing it.

I am assuming there will be some sort of epsilon approach but I am not exactly sure.
Any tips or suggestions to help get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up the theorem of Cesaro-Stolz, this seems to be a slight generalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S=\limsup\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{c_{n+1}-c_n}$ then for any $ε>0$ the number $S+ε$ is an upper bound for almost all of the fractions. Let the exceptions be bounded by $N-1$, then for all $k\ge N$
$$
a_{k+1}-a_k\le(S+ε)(c_{k+1}-c_k)
$$
Sum this up from $k=N$ to $n-1$ to get
$$
a_n-a_N\le(S+ε)(c_n-c_N)\implies \frac{a_n}{c_n}\le \frac{a_N}{c_n}+(S+ε)(1-\frac{c_N}{c_n})
$$
and for $n\to\infty $ the right side converges to $S+ε$ which makes $S+2ε$ an upper bound for almost all of the fractions $\frac{a_n}{c_n}$.